# Setting up OpenLDAP + slapo-translucent on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up a local LDAP server with local entry customizations that lays on top of an existing LDAP directory that we provide (which is read-only). From what I'm seeing, it looks like slapo-translucent is exactly what I need. However, I'm seeing a ton of conflicting information on the web on how to configure OpenLDAP for overlays, since there's some new LDIF configuration format, and the old slapd.conf configuration is deprecated/gone.

I already have slapd installed and running on my Ubuntu instance. Does anyone have any good pointers on where to go to set up overlays?

Thanks!
Cody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps you to get started, it's still possible to configure slapd in the old-fashioned way with slapd.conf and then convert that to new format.

```
slaptest -f /etc/ldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

Above would convert `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` to the new format, putting the needed data files in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`. Just remember to create the destination directory before running the command.

Comment: Ahhh, that's awesome - I didn't know you could still use the old format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On my CentOS 5, just install the `openldap-servers-overlays` package, load the module:

```
modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload translucent.la
```

and follow the [document](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) on the home page.